# #states visible

Tags: 8, javascript

The states visible seems to work correct in D7. In D8 I want to test make a field visable if one OR another field have a value. And also when two fields  have a value. What I have below works if both fields have a value.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\State\StateInterface;

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface     &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_form') {
    $form['field_format']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="field_item_type"]' => array('value' => 'tv_show'),
          'or',
          ':input[name="field_extra"]' => array('value' => 'bike'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Fix like that : 'visible' => array(
          array( ':input[name="field_item_type"]' => array('value' => 'tv_show') ),
          'or',
          array( ':input[name="field_extra"]' => array('value' => 'bike') ),
      ),

Answer (score 12):

Try the below code .It works .

```
$form['field_item_type'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Title must be at least 5 characters in length.'),
  '#options' => ['tv_show'=> 'Tv show','serials' => 'Serials']
];
$form['field_extra'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Title must be at least 5 characters in length.'),
  '#options' => ['movie' => 'movie','chair'=>'Chair'],
];
$form['field_format'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Title must be at least 5 characters in length.'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
];
$form['field_format']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    [
      [':input[name="field_item_type"]' => ['value' => 'tv_show']],
      'or',
      [':input[name="field_extra"]' => ['value' => 'movie']],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot :)