# Hiding view filter option based on another filter selection

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view with search criteria and the search criteria looks like below:

Age group(options: new born, toddler, pre-school)
Classroom (options: NA, potty-trained, transition, not-trained) All these filter fields are check boxes.

When I select 'new born' as age-group, all of the classroom options should be hidden/disabled except NA option When I select 'toddler/pre-school' all of the classroom options should show up again except NA option

I am using the below code for doing this:

```
$('#edit-field-agegroup-value-1').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#edit-field-classroom-value-3").prop('disabled', true);
     } else {
        $("#edit-field-classroom-value-3").prop('disabled', false); 
     }
    });
```

This code is working fine. However, when I submit the refresh button the page refreshes and the disabled fields show enabled again. Any help on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#states visible](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230197/states-visible)

Comment: That's a job for Form API #states. If you are asking for JS that would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Run the check on page page load, not just on click:

```
 ... wrapped in the usual Drupal boilerplate

disableFilter($('#edit-field-agegroup-value-1'));

$('#edit-field-agegroup-value-1').click(function() {
    disableFilter($(this));
});

function disableFilter(element) {
    if( element.is(':checked')) {
        $("#edit-field-classroom-value-3").prop('disabled', true);
     } else {
        $("#edit-field-classroom-value-3").prop('disabled', false); 
     }    
}
```